# Can I register data in SQL Server from an Angular project without using .NET Core?

Tags: sql-server, angular, .net-core, angular5

I want to know if I can capture data from a form made with Angular and save it in a SQL Server table without using .NET Core.

Comment: Angular needs a server side API (built in any language/technology) to store data to a server. It is, at the end of it, JavaScript that can run in browser. It needs server JS (node), or .NET Core Web API, or Java Web Services, or any number of server side tech that will eventually store data in the backend database (SQL, in your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net core is not the issue،the subject is that you required a back end api that save your data on sql server to http requst.
.net core,nodejs,and...